# Add primary key to an existing field in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, migration

Once upon a time I made a join table with no `id`:

```
create_table :products_stores, id: false do |t|
  t.belongs_to :app
  t.belongs_to :product
end
```

I later wanted to use it for the position of each product:

```
rename_table :products_stores, :inventories
add_column :inventories, :position, :integer
```

and *incorrectly* added a primary key with:

```
add_column :inventories, :id, :integer, primary: true
```

Instead of:

```
add_column :inventories, :id, :primary_key
```

How do I fix this, or in other words, how do I add a primary key to an existing column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
execute('ALTER TABLE inventories ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);')
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try

```
change_column :inventories, :id, :primary_key
```

you could also try to rollback the migration with the error and fix it before migrating again.

Comment: Unfortunately I get `PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "primary" LINE 1: ...TABLE "inventories" ALTER COLUMN "id" TYPE serial primary ke...`

Comment: Could you post the full error and the schema for the tabel?

Comment: Sure. I'm using a test app for this so it's got almost nothing in it but it should help to diagnose: http://pastie.org/8877877

Comment: If there's almost nothing in there, you could also try my other suggestion; rollback your migration with the error and fix it there.

Comment: Yup, I actually did end up fixing the problem by dropping the database, but I wanted to know what I might do in a situation that that would destroy data.

Comment: also, your table still has the id:false. Maybe try change_table "users", id: true

Comment: Just tried `id: true` There is no error, but the schema says the same.

Answer (score 0):

I had a requirement to remove rails generated primary key field id and make an already existing column a primary key. To achieve this I removed the id column and and added primary key as per @Edward Loveall answer.

```
remove_column :my_table, :id, :bigint
execute('ALTER TABLE my_table ADD PRIMARY KEY (my_id_column);')
```